# Can listing the elements of a list in a list, in order?

Tags: python, list

I want to make an element in a list in a list a list of first ones and second ones.

For example,

from

```py
test = [['Aa', 'Ba', 'Ca', 'Da'], ['Ab', 'Bb', 'Cb', 'Db'], ['Ac', 'Bc', 'Cc', 'Dc']]
```

to

```py
result = [['Aa', 'Ab', 'Ac'], ['Ba', 'Bb', 'Bc'], ['Ca', 'Cb', 'Cc'], ['Da', 'Db',  'Dc']]
```

I can do something like this, but if the numbers in the list change, I can't do this.

```py
list(zip(test[0], test[1],test[2]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the unpacking operator:

```
list(zip(*test))
```

which will give you a list of tuples or

```
[list(t) for t in zip(*test)]
```

which will give you a list of lists.

Comment: `list(map(list, zip(*test)))` for inner lists.